# Exchange values in a specific set of 3 variables in R and perform the same permutation in other sets of 3 variables

Tags: r, sorting, permutation

I have a data set in which I have one set of 3 numeric (potentially NA) variables AoFE_L1, AoFE_L2, AoFE_L3 that I need to re-organise in R so that in AoFE_L1 is the smallest value, in AoFE_L2 the second smallest and in AoFE_L3 the highest value.
This potential permutation should then be performed also on other sets of 3 variables L1, L2, L3; PoFE_L1, PoFE_L2, PoFE_L3.

Here is an example/fictive data set:

```
data <- data.frame( 
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
AoFE_L1 = c(0, 5, 0, 2, 18), 
AoFE_L2 = c(0, 0, 8, NA, 7), 
AoFE_L3 = c(NA, 2, 9, NA, NA), 
L1 = c("German", "French", "German", "English", "Italian"), 
L2 = c("French", "German", "English", NA, "German"), 
L3 = c(NA, "English", "French", NA, NA), 
PoFE_L1 = c("home", "school", "home", "home", "school"), 
PoFE_L2 = c("home", "home", "school", NA, "school"), 
PoFE_L3 = c(NA, "home", "school", NA, NA) 
)
```

The variables "AoFE_L1", "AoFE_L2" and "AoFE_L3" are the ones that I want to order in ascending order (e.g., ID1 ID3, ID4 are okay, ID2 and ID5 need to be re-arranged.
The final/expected data set should look like that:

```
data <- data.frame( 
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
AoFE_L1 = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 7), 
AoFE_L2 = c(0, 2, 8, NA, 18), 
AoFE_L3 = c(NA, 5, 9, NA, NA), 
L1 = c("German", "German", "German", "English", "German"), 
L2 = c("French", "English", "English", NA, "Italian"), 
L3 = c(NA, "French", "French", NA, NA), 
PoFE_L1 = c("home", "home", "home", "home", "school"), 
PoFE_L2 = c("home", "home", "school", NA, "school"), 
PoFE_L3 = c(NA, "school", "school", NA, NA) 
)
```

I tried different ways of recoding the variables of the first set which works but I do not know any way of "storing" this permutation somewhere to apply it also on other sets of 3 variables in the same data set.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

After your second explanation I have an idea about the data format and I think I have a solution for you.

```
library(data.table)

# your data
d <- data.table( 
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
  AoFE_L1 = c(0, 5, 0, 2, 18), 
  AoFE_L2 = c(0, 0, 8, NA, 7), 
  AoFE_L3 = c(NA, 2, 9, NA, NA), 
  L1 = c("German", "French", "German", "English", "Italian"), 
  L2 = c("French", "German", "English", NA, "German"), 
  L3 = c(NA, "English", "French", NA, NA), 
  PoFE_L1 = c("home", "school", "home", "home", "school"), 
  PoFE_L2 = c("home", "home", "school", NA, "school"), 
  PoFE_L3 = c(NA, "home", "school", NA, NA) 
)


# melt data to long format for your three measure variables
d <- melt(d,measure.vars = list(2:4,5:7,8:10),value.name  = c("AoFE","L","PoFE"))

# order on "AoFE" by ID
setorderv(d,c("ID","AoFE"),na.last = TRUE)

# as you can see the data is still in long format and I recommend to
#  keep it that way. The logical data structure is observations in 
#  rows and variables in columns.. If you really need it to be in
#  wide format you can use dcast() to change it back to wide format.
print(d)

    ID variable AoFE       L   PoFE
 1:  1        1    0  German   home
 2:  1        2    0  French   home
 3:  1        3   NA    <NA>   <NA>
 4:  2        2    0  German   home
 5:  2        3    2 English   home
 6:  2        1    5  French school
 7:  3        1    0  German   home
 8:  3        2    8 English school
 9:  3        3    9  French school
10:  4        1    2 English   home
11:  4        2   NA    <NA>   <NA>
12:  4        3   NA    <NA>   <NA>
13:  5        2    7  German school
14:  5        1   18 Italian school
15:  5        3   NA    <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I guess that maybe my description was not completely clear since unfortunately with the data.table() it seems to me that it would not work in my case.

Here is a longer description:

Comment: Hey, I edited my first answer and might now have to solution to your problem. I think you should also delete the answer you left to your own post.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! This worked very well and now I will try to continue with the data table in long format.

Comment: Hi @mooh!
Working with your code for a couple of days now has worked quite well. Unfortunately, since yesterday I always receive the error message
"Error: measure variables not found in data: 2:4, 5:7, 8:10".
Have you an idea why this may be the case?
Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: 2:4, 5:7 and 8:10 etc are the column indices of the 3 groups to melt into long format. My guess is that your input data has changed format.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I checked with exactly the example that you had prepared which should not have changed in the meantime. So I was wondering whether there may be something wrong that is not visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(Rfast)

x <- 1:nrow(data) + (rowOrder(as.matrix(data[,2:4])) - 1)*nrow(data)
data[2:4] <- data[2:4][x]
data[5:7] <- data[5:7][x]
data[8:10] <- data[8:10][x]
data
#>   ID AoFE_L1 AoFE_L2 AoFE_L3      L1      L2     L3 PoFE_L1 PoFE_L2 PoFE_L3
#> 1  1       0       0      NA  German  French   <NA>    home    home    <NA>
#> 2  2       0       2       5  German English French    home    home  school
#> 3  3       0       8       9  German English French    home  school  school
#> 4  4       2      NA      NA English    <NA>   <NA>    home    <NA>    <NA>
#> 5  5       7      18      NA  German Italian   <NA>  school  school    <NA>
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
data[2:10] <- data[matrix(outer(1:nrow(data) + rowOrder(as.matrix(data[,2:4]))*nrow(data), (0:2)*3*nrow(data), "+"), nrow(data))]
```